# Solving simple system 2 eqs 2 unknwns

Tags: equation-solving

Can't get Mathematica to solve a simple system. Takes 30 secs to do it by hand, but when asking Mathematica to do

```
Solve[W1 - a*W2^k1 == 0 && W2 - b*W1^k2 == 0, {W1, W2}]
```

It tells me "Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables." and then `W2 -> E^((-Log[a] + Log[W1])/k1)`

Comment: What solution do you expect? You said, you can do it by hand...

Comment: You can express W2 from 2nd equation and substitute into 1st, to get $W1=a*b^{k1}*W1^{k1k2}$, and then solve this for W1

Comment: Things are usually not as easy. Have a look at this: `y = x /. Solve[a x^b == x, x][[1]];
Plot3D[Abs[a y^b - y], {a, -1, 1}, {b, -1, 1}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"a", "b"}]`

Comment: Are there restrictions on `a, b, k1, k2`? Are they complex/real/rational/integer? Are they positive/negative?

Comment: I want to solve the system symbolically. All parameters are real, but when manipulating the expressions Mathematica can only proceed under additional assumption, I expect it to tell me smth like : "Here is the solution, the condition is $a$ and $b$ are positive"

Comment: But `W2 -> E^((-Log[a] + Log[W1])/k1)` **is** the symbolic solution when you don't have any conditions on `a` and `b`. It doesn't get any prettier than that.

Comment: Marius, what do you mean "solution"? It's a system with 2 unknowns W1 and W2. I want to compute W1 as a function that doesn't depend on W2. Basically, I want to get $W1=(a*b^{k1})^{1/(1-k1*k2)}$